# Why is file_get_contents returning page source?

Tags: php, shortcode, csv

I'm trying to write a shortcode in my theme's **functions.php** file that can display the contents of a CSV file on our server.

I'll worry about reading the CSV file into arrays and such later, but for now I just want to make sure I can read a file's contents using **file_get_contents**. However, when I run the shortcode below, the alert contains HTML.

```
function display_csv_data_func( $atts ) {
   $file_contents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/something/file.csv");
   return "<script>alert('" . $file_contents . "');</script>";
}
add_shortcode( 'display_csv_data', 'display_csv_data_func' );
```

returns:

```
alert('
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en-US"
...
```

Is there something about shortcodes, functions.php or WordPress in general that's interfering with my code? Seems like this should be a fairly simple thing to do...

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the contents of the HTML that's being returned.

Comment: My 1st guess is that the HTML that you're getting is a 404 (or other error) page from example.com.  That is, are you sure the URL in your `file_get_contents()` call is correct?   If you enter that URL in a browser, do you get the .csv file or something else?

Comment: @Aaron The HTML is pretty lengthy, what are you looking for specifically?

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron I'm positive that the URL is correct, as I can navigate to it and fopen is also successful.

Comment: Does `wp_remote_get()` work?

Comment: @moraleida Yep! I just figured that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I figured it out! You have to use **wp_remote_get()**. I'm not exactly sure why at this point, but here's what the code looks like:

```
function display_csv_data_func( $atts ) {
   $file_path = "http://example.com/something/file.csv";
   $response = wp_remote_get($file_path);
   $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
   return "<script>alert('" . $response_body . "');</script>";
}
add_shortcode( 'display_csv_data', 'display_csv_data_func' );
```