# Why wp_remote_get() fetches certain web pages while it doesn't work for my localhost?

Tags: php, shortcode, page-template

Why I'm not able to parse csv files (or equivalently open them) using WordPress shortcode?

Problem: I wish to use a shortcode to Parse Contents of a csv file and display its contents effectively. But the problem is that for some reason, the file doesn't opens/shows up despite different turn arounds. The server logs say that the GET request to the file was successful.

My Shortcode:

```
function wpb_demo_shortcode() { 
    if (($open = fopen("http://localhost:8000/a.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
  {
  
    while (($data = fgetcsv($open, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {        
      $array[] = $data; 
    }
  
    fclose($open);
  }
  echo "<pre>";
  //To display array data
  var_dump($array);
  echo "</pre>";
}
add_shortcode('website-url-name', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

There are similar questions around: [Why is file_get_contents returning page source?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258869/why-is-file-get-contents-returning-page-source)

Again the solution returns no different. It's showing a blank pop up for me. I don't even know what's the problem with WordPress because regular plain PHP script is able to render it successfully.

Kindly enlighten the mistake here.

EDIT: I just found that instead of using localhost:8000, I used https://pippinsplugins.com/edd-api/products and it works like a magic. I don't know why it is not able to get files files from my localhost. Very weird.

some ss regarding shortcode being called and output.

[image]

Comment: So you tried `wp_remote_get()` and it really didn't work? Have you confirmed the request actually responded with a valid CSV file/data? And you mentioned "blank pop up" - what pop up? How did you call your shortcode? Also, `$array` should be defined before adding items to that array.. And note that shortcodes must always **return** the output and not echo anything because doing so can break many things, e.g. it will invalidate REST API's JSON responses.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, GET requests to server are successful for localhost:8000 from Server Logs. Also, everything regarding $array and all are perfectly setup because it responds well to other website (link given in question) and it doesn't works same when I replace the website to localhost:8000/a.json, where both json files are same too.

Comment: "from Server Logs" - how about, for testing, try `var_dump( wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( 'http://localhost:8000/a.csv' ) ) )` ? Does it output a valid CSV string? If all else fails, try moving the file to somewhere else, change its permissions, etc..